# I can't get the right items to boot on ubuntu-16.04 and systemd

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I needed to make a new image and opted for the new 16.04 ubuntu so I could get newer versions of some packages and not install from source.  So far, I regret that decision as online docs are sparse.

With 12.04 and 14.04, I was often able to re-purpose the startup scripts for custom compilations by installing a package, then removeing (not purging) it, to create the ubuntu startup scripts.  Then I could just edit them to point to the right config file and binary.

For example, to use the latest openresty I could just do this:

```
apt-get install nginx
apt-get remove nginx
```

Then I could just update the `/etc/init.d/nginx` script to point to my custom binary/config file and I have a happy ubuntu startup script.  Great!

This method doesn't work with 16.04 anymore.

I've edited:

- `/etc/init.d/nginx`
- `/etc/init/nginx.conf`
- `/lib/system.d/system/nginx.service`

ubuntu never pulls my binary (which is in `/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx`).  it always runs `/sbin/nginx` on bootup (i missed uninstalling 'nginx-core' at first) or nothing at all.  The same holds true for other packages.

Ubuntu's docs on the transition from upstart are lacking in this area, they're concerned with "start stop".

I have *no idea* where ubuntu is deciding this.  i can't find any config files that point to `/sbin/nginx`.  No logs help.  Every potential file I've come across points to the alternate binary and config.

If anyone can share a good resource on using the new launch system and where it looks/store info, I would be incredibly grateful.

There seems to be a database involved, as it's detected file-changes and asked me to reload -- but I haven't found it.

## update

after toying around a lot, I figured the following out:

It seems that the nginx package installed two types of setups but only uses one. some issues were tied to that.

1. `/etc/init.d/nginx` and `/etc/init/nginx.conf`
2. `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service` and `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service`

from trial and error:
 * run `systemctl disable nginx.service` to disable/delete most links and files
 * remove file in /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service if it exists
 * place a new file in /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service
 * run `systemctl enable nginx.service`

the file in /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service must be a file; it can't be symlink (otherwise a too many symlinks error appears)

this seems to work for now.  i wish i could use symlinks as these files are tied to version control.

Comment: The systemd project page https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/ links to a a number of tutorials and documentation where the blog posts "systemd for administrators" series is a good start.

Answer (score 5):

Could you create a new service for your custom install, then make it autostart?

```
[Unit]
Description=Jonathan Vanasco nginx

[Service]
ExecStart=STARTUP COMMAND YOU WANT FOR CUSTOM

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then check it starts:

```
systemctl start NAMEOFCUSTOM.service
```

Then set to auto-start on boot:

```
systemctl enable NAMEOFCUSTOM.service
```

Comment: what if it prompts you for password, and says it is enabled, but the script still doesn't run?

Comment: oh, never mind `/bin/bash /path-to-cmd start` http://stackoverflow.com/a/15146271/2496266